appcenter login issue on Mac
I am using a Mac system and getting this issue, Can someone tell me how to fix it??
appcenter login --token 0fb553a71f6d4dcbf9c7a820114b76af5bc2a828
| Getting user info ...node:internal/errors:932
const err = new Error(message);
^
Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/security find-generic-password -a me18 -s mobile-center-cli -g
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12) {

code: 44,
killed: false,
signal: null,
cmd: '/usr/bin/security find-generic-password -a me18 -s mobile-center-cli -g'
}
I have tried this command but it is not working..
security unlock-keychain /Users/xxxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
I have also uninstalled and installed appcenter again and again

If unlocking the keychain by running security unlock-keychain /Users/xxxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db and re-installing appcenter did not solve the issue, try these steps

rm -rf ~/.appcenter-cli/profile.json <-- this will remove the current appcenter profile that is being used for login, can also check this by catting its contents
appcenter login ... <-- login again using your preferred method


Thank you for your response. Apparently it got resolved by restarting everything and reinstalling it.
